# Not showing Year values in mySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import data from csv file with below command line for data which is kept in E drive and file name is data.csv:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:\data.csv' 
into table prize_won fields 
terminated by ',' lines 
terminated by '\n';
```

The data file has headers Year,subject,winner,country and category respectively.
Now when i try to import it with above command, some year aren't showing in tables and some are visible however rest of entries seems fine.

Can you please suggest a possible solution?

My data.csv file contents look like

```
1970    Physics      Hannes Alfven    Sweden    Scientist
1970    Physics      Louis Neel       France    Scientist
1970    Chemistry    Luis Federico    France    Scientist
1970    Physiology   Ulf von Euler    Sweden    Scientist
```

Comment: Please add your table definition and one or two example records from your csv file.

Comment: So inspect the CSV data for the rows that don't contain the proper content and see what's wrong. We can't do so from here. You have the rest of the data for the rows that are missing the year, so search for that row in the CSV file and see what might be wrong with it.

Comment: @KenWhite i was going through same procedure but unable to find if i missed anything while creating table like considering it a char or int makes a difference and also selecting content of excel cell as text or numbers makes a difference but couldn't find it

Comment: Your question is making less sense. Your `LOAD DATA` statement above says `fields terminated by ','`, but the image you posted shows `fields terminated by '|'`. The *CSV file* image you posted shows an Excel worksheet containing data, not a .CSV file (which contains lines like `123,Smith,John` or `123|Smith|John`, not data neatly displayed in cells without any commas or separators). Open the .CSV file using Notepad or another text editor, which will let you look at the raw content before Excel manipulates it during loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, the problem was with the format of cell contents like text or number or General etc.
So for the year i selected the format as number and made sure it doesn't have any digits after decimal and for the rest of column i have selected format as texts after loading the data all the entries are coming clean.

Answer (score 0):

Open your csv in text editor so you can see if the formatting (the enclosers, delimiters) is consistent. Normally you should be able to see double quotes on some fields. The double quotes would be the `enclosed by '"'` line that's missing in your statement but is the default for parsing CSV in mySQL.